# Image Preloading

Tags: performance

Why does WordPress pre-download every image/icon/etc?

Running my website through the tester at http://tools.pingdom.com/, I can see that it is downloading a bunch of icons and image files that definitely aren't even referenced in that page.

Any ideas how to disable this to improve page-load time?

Answer (score 4):

I think Pingdom Tools gives you a false image. I opened your website (`advia.com.au`?) in Chrome with the Developer Tools open, and it loads 57 items, not 146 as Pingdom Tools shows. I think Pingdom Tools just scans the HTML and CSS files and loads all images it finds there - you have 113 `url()` references in your `screen.css` file for example (click on *"Show link hierarchy"* to make this clear in Pingdom Tools). Most browsers will only load these when they are needed.